# How and when did the Latin alphabet become predominant over Jawi in Malaysia?

Tags: language, malaysia

The [Jawi alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jawi_alphabet) is still used in Malaysia, and there are certain policies that promote its continued use, but Latin script is far more dominant. At what point did the Malay population as a whole become largely literate in Latinized Malay? Was this already the case at the time of independence?

Comment: [This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20141104140207/http://www.englishspellingsociety.org/journals/j11/malay.php), cited in a Wikipedia article on [Rumi spelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Rumi_Spelling), points at "Malay vernacular schools" introduced in rural Malaysia by the British at the begining of the 20th century. cit.: "For this literacy program in Malay, the British colonial government decided to use the Roman alphabet as a writing system for writing Malay."

Comment: @ccprog you should make that an answer.